# parenthesis and curly braces difference in golang

Tags: go

```
a := []byte("H") //works
a := []byte{"H"} //does not compile
```

What is the conceptual difference between () and {} as used above?

Comment: The first is a type conversion of string to []byte. The second is formally a []byte literal with one element; but of course a string cannot be a byte so this one fails. Your really should take the Tour of Go and read the language spec.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is the difference between [type conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) and [slice literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

```
_ = []byte("Hi!")         // Converts a string literal to a []byte.
_ = []byte{'H', 'i', '!'} // Initializes a []byte literal
```

Your second example `[]byte{"H"}` fails to compile because `"H"` is a *string* literal that is being used in place of a [*rune* literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), it's comparable to trying to assign a string to a byte typed variable:

```
var y byte = 'H' // OK
var x byte = "H" // ERROR: cannot use "H" (type string) as type byte in assignment
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first one `a := []byte("H")` you are type casting the string `"H"` into a byte array.

In the second one `a := []byte{"H"}` you are defining a byte array and assigning "H" as it's first value, which is invalid.

You can compare the second one with defining a string array:

```
s := []string{"hello","world",".."} // works
f := []string{1,2,4} // fails because the datatype is wrong
```